# Trying to prepend leading zero and decimal to number Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, function

I'm having some trouble trying to prepend a leading zero and decimal in Javascript whilst maintaining the number format. I'm able to do this successfully as a string, but when trying to utilise a `parseInt()`, it strips the leading zero and decimal and converts to a whole number.

The end goal I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. `0.5000`
2. `0.0500`

And, if less numbers are given:

1. `0.50`
2. `0.05`

I have a function that takes a number, and an optional boolean value to determine whether to do the above, utilising a JS switch:

```js
function formatTrainingDigit(number, decimals) {
  var numberSplit = number.toString().split('')
  if (decimals) {
    switch (numberSplit.length) {
      case 1:
        return '0.0' + number // TODO: this returns string, change to number.
        break;
      case 2:
        return '0.' + number // TODO: this returns string, change to number.
        break;
      case 3:
        return '0.' + number // TODO: this returns string, change to number.
        break;
      case 4:
        return '0.' + number // TODO: this returns string, change to number.
        break;
      default:
        return 0.00
    }
  } else {
    switch (numberSplit.length) {
      case 1:
        return 0,0,0,parseInt(numberSplit[0])
        break;
      case 2:
        return 0,0,parseInt(numberSplit[0]),parseInt(numberSplit[1])
        break;
      case 3:
        return 0,parseInt(numberSplit[0]),parseInt(numberSplit[1]),parseInt(numberSplit[2])
        break;
      case 4:
        return parseInt(numberSplit[0]),parseInt(numberSplit[1]),parseInt(numberSplit[2]),parseInt(numberSplit[3])
        break;
      default:
        return 0,0,0,0
    }
  }
}
```

I'd be passing values into the function as: `formatTrainingDigit(5000, false)` or `formatTrainingDigit(50, true)`

However, when trying to then do a `parseInt()` on my returned function, it strips everything, e.g:

This works: `console.log(formatTrainingDigit(5000, true)) // returns string`
This fails: `console.log(parseInt(formatTrainingDigit(5000, true))) // returns number zero`

Comment: Why not use `Number.prototype.toFixed`

Comment: Why do you use `parseInt` if you need a float/decimal value? Have you tried to use `parseFloat`?

Comment: `parseFloat()` also strips the extra leading zeros.

Comment: @MaheerAli This is giving me `5000.00` I need `0.5000` when using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score -1):

You can use **toFixed** method of number. below is an example.

```js
function addZeroes( num ) {
   var value;
    var res;
    if(typeof num== "number")
       {
         value = (num);
         res = num.toString().split(".");
       
       }
      else{ 
     value = Number(num);
     res = num.split(".");
     }
    if(res.length == 1 || (res[1].length < 3)) {
        value = value.toFixed(4);
    }
    return value
}

var ww = '0.01'
var xx = 5
var yy = .5
var zz = '4.567'
console.log(addZeroes(ww));
console.log(addZeroes(xx));
console.log(addZeroes(yy));
console.log(addZeroes(zz));
```

Comment: This isn't correct. This returns `5000.0000` when passing a `String` I'm passing a `Number` and need: `0.5000`